# Swift - help solving crash "Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0" - specific case

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a problem with a crash in an app (from which I have not been able to recreate, but I have the error message for). I think I know the general area that is causing it but cannot pinpoint it. The exact crash message as as follows:

> Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException - Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (8) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (10), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

This exact error has occurred multiple times. The difference between this and other similar problems on stack overflow is that there seems to be 2 rows less than the original (10) after the update (a deletion) which is causing the problem.

For all of the questions I've seen involve the number of rows before and after being equal e.g. 5 rows before and 5 rows after a deletion.
But in this case it goes down by 2 rows after 1 deletion.

The usual advice that is given to resolve this is to change the data array before removing the tableview cell but that is not the issue here as the code below shows.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
     guard let section = self.sections?[indexPath.section],
     let product = section.products?[indexPath.row] else { return nil }
     let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: 
     "ActionText") { 
     [weak self] (action, indexPath) in
           self?.remove(product: product, in: section, at: indexPath)
     }
     return [delete]
}

func remove(product: BasketProduct, in section: BasketTableViewSection, at indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    guard let basket = self.basket, let index = 
    basket.products.firstIndex(where: { $0==product }) else { return }
    basket.products.remove(at: index)
    self.basket = basket

//Some code happens here that saves the changes to the data(basket) array 
// to a database but I won't show as it is unimportant.

    if section.products?.count == 1 {
        self.tableView.deleteSections(IndexSet(integer: 
        indexPath.section), with: .right)
    } else {
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .right)
    }

    self.updateBasket(reconfigureView: false) 
    { [weak self] in

        UIView.runOnMainThread {
             self?.tableView.endUpdates()
        }

}
```

*** the definition for "updateBasket" is rather lengthy so was omitted. What's worth mentioning is that it had a tableView.reloadData method in it.

Is there anything that looks off that looks like it could be causing an error like that here? If maybe a pointer in the right direction? What's usually the fix for this particular error?